# Getting script to run when button clicked in Electron

Tags: html, electron

I am working on an application in Electron, on this page I have put a button however the script does not run when clicked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link class="menu-bar" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
        <link class="main" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/ceaser.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Cipher Program</title>

    </head>

<body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <ul class = "menu-bar">
        <li><a href="index.html"> Menu </a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="ceaser.html">Ceaser Cipher</a></li>
        <li><a href="vernam.html">Vernam Cipher </a></li>
        <li><a href="frequency.html">Frequency Analysis</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="main">

        <h1>Ceaser Cipher</h1>
        <button type="button" onclick="test()">Click me </button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test() {
            console.log("got this far")
        }
        </script>

    </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some cdn for .js to work with javascript library functions as i see theres no library imported to work with javascript like
           `<script src="your_js/cdn"....></script>`

Answer (score 0):

your Code should output something in the Browserconsole.
You can open the Developertools afaik with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.

To output / connect with the Mainapplication you should use IPC.
See: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

Greets

Answer (score 0):

Console.log will display text in a terminal window. If you are trying to display something in a browser you have to change the DOM.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link class="menu-bar" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
        <link class="main" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/ceaser.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Cipher Program</title>

    </head>

<body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <ul class = "menu-bar">
        <li><a href="index.html"> Menu </a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="ceaser.html">Ceaser Cipher</a></li>
        <li><a href="vernam.html">Vernam Cipher </a></li>
        <li><a href="frequency.html">Frequency Analysis</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="main">

        <h1>Ceaser Cipher</h1>
        <div id="message"></div>
        <button type="button" onclick="test()">Click me </button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test() {
            console.log("got this far");
            
  document.getElementById("message").appendChild(document.createTextNode("You see me now"));
        }
        </script>        

    </div>
</body>
```

Simplest way is to create an empty "div" with id of your choosing. Then in javascript use the document object "document" and it's functions like ".write" or ".appendChild" to change the DOM.

You should be able to run the above code in the stack overflow sandbox and see that the output to terminal (console.log) is different than the browser rendered DOM (getElementById("message").appendChild)